# How can I control many threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have many pages from where I download content from the web. Each web page is handled in one thread. How can I tell Java, that I want maximum 500 threads run at one time and if one thread is finished, the next one will start so that I have the best performance?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: 500 threads won't help, you should use asynchronous HTTP client and divide your task into realistic number of threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using `ExecutorService` and `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500)`.

There are lot of tutorials on this on the web. For e.g., start with [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) one.